# Python evaluate datetimes when one datetime is None

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I'm wondering how a None datetime is evaluated in Python 2.7.

Specifically;

`trial_exp_date < datetime.utcnow() #trial_exp_date = None`

If a user was never on a trial then the trial_exp_date will be None, in that case I'm wondering if the above evaluation will evaluate to True of False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try it out in the python interpreter.

```
from datetime import datetime
None < datetime.utcnow()
```

This gives a TypeError. The reason it does so is because the datetime module has no concept of comparisons between a datetime object and None. You can deal with this by checking beforehand to see if trial_exp_date is None and if so doing whatever is necessary, i.e:

```
if trial_exp_date is not None:
    return trial_exp_date < datetime.utcnow()
else:
    # handle the case where the user never was on a trial
```

Comment: `trial_exp_date and trial_exp_date < datetime.utcnow()` could be used to find out whether it is known that `trial_exp_date` is in the past.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, None was originally always less that any data type ([see code for cpython](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Objects/object.c#l778)) On line 779, you see `/* None is smaller than anything */` followed by the evaluation code. However, it seems this was back ported in the (relevant to you) case of Python 2.7. If you look at [Data Types](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), you see:

> **Changed in version 2.7**: The complex type no longer makes implicit calls to the `__coerce__()` method for mixed-type binary arithmetic operations.

Although, **2.6** documentation is confusing because [it says](https://docs.python.org/2.6/reference/datamodel.html):

> Arguments to rich comparison methods are never coerced.

***In the end, you should check for it regardless.***

The change in certainly in with Python 3 ([see what's new](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons)) which throws type errors instead:

> Python 3.0 has simplified the rules for ordering comparisons:
>
> The ordering comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) raise a `TypeError` exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering. Thus, expressions like: `1 < ''`, `0 > None` or `len <= len` are no longer valid, and e.g. `None < None` raises `TypeError` instead of returning `False`. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note that this does not apply to the `==` and `!=` operators: objects of different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.

You can get around this problem with an explicit date which your logic should use to indicate not expired: `(trial_exp_date or date_you_pick) < datetime.utcnow()` Where this date is calculated in a way that it's always in the future or it's a specific date far far in the future. The first won't break in a hundred years, but the second, to me is more explicite / readable. You need the parantheses due to the [order of precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) in Python.

Comment: I thought that too but `None < datetime.utcnow()` raises `TypeError` even on Python 2

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I updated my answer to note that though I found this implementation in the C code, 2.7 also calls this new and 2.6 seems to call it out (but without calling it new). I guess the important thing is to not leave it to chance regardless.